# Node login not working: I think it's stuck in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**Hello lovely people, here's my code. Can anyone help me? Thank you!**

**Browser tells me that it has redirected me too many times, I've read somewhere else that it means it might be stuck in a loop... Or maybe something else is wrong... I'm doing this for an online course and the teacher doesn't explain much, so it's quite confusing D:**

**I'm new to coding, please be kind**

```
import express from "express";
import config from "./config";
import morgan from "morgan";
import cors from "cors";
import path from "path";
import ejs from "ejs";

var session = require('express-session');



var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookieParser');

var loginRouter = require('./routes/admin/login');


import contact from "./routes/contact";


const app = express();

app.set("PORT", config.PORT);

app.get("/", (_, res) => res.render("admin/login.hbs"));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({
    secret:'dasajk453sdhas234dkl534jasdjk',
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized:true
}));


var secured = async(req,res,next) => {
    try{
        if(req.session.id_usuario){
            return res.redirect('/home');
        }else{
            res.redirect('/admin/login');
        }
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}


app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(express.json());

app.use("/contact", contact);
app.use('/admin/login', loginRouter);

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.get(cookieParser());

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.get("/home", secured, (req, res)=>res.render("index.hbs"));



export default app;
```

Comment: Add the code of `loginRouter` for a better understanding.

Comment: Here it is! SO won't let me share directly https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hdT9fteVgpQiqkviuQVJHHpx8OZMnyBO/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing recursive redirects to `/home`.

**Here when u r doing post request to `/admin/login`**

```
router.post('/', async(req,res,next) => {
    try{
    var usuario = req.body.usuario;
    var password = req.body.password;

    console.log(req.body);

    var data = await usuariosModel.getUserandPassword(usuario,password);

    if(data != undefined){
        req.session.id_usuario = data.id; <------ You are adding id to session here
        req.session.nombre = data.usuario;
        res.redirect('/home'); <------- At this point u r redirecting to '/home' 
    }else {
        res.render('admin/login', {
            layout: 'admin/layout',
            error:true
        });
      }


    }catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

---

**On coming to `/home`, you are checking `secured` using middleware**

```
var secured = async(req,res,next) => { <----- you are checking for `/home`
    try{
        if(req.session.id_usuario){ <----- Here u r again checking if id is present, then again redirect to `/home`, which is creating a loop of redirects. You need to resolve this.
        //You need to do a next() here, i guess
            return res.redirect('/home');
        }else{
            res.redirect('/admin/login');
        }
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

`Note: This should resolve ur error. Check your middleware otherwise and try each routing flow for clarification`

Comment: changed  return res.redirect('/home'); for next(); and nothing D:. thank you for your kind answer

Comment: whenever I add next(); it doesn't let me enter the homepage regardless of the username and password being right and I don't understand why

Comment: add the code with `next()`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dimeHMUcdHhgWE8O5LHQKhNwwaeyyV14/view?usp=sharing

Comment: what is `getUserandPassword` and are u using Mongo? check `data` returned from `getUserandPassword`. You have some other error. Debug the whole flow using `console.log()`

Comment: you can make a codesandbox of your code so that others can run and debug as well.

Comment: var pool = require('./bd');
var MD5 = require('MD5');

async function getUserandPassword(usuario,password){
    try{
        var query = 'select * from usuarios where usuario = ? and password = ? limit 1'
        var rows = await pool.query(query,[usuario,MD5(password)])
        return rows[0];

    }catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}

module.exports = { getUserandPassword }